# View Custom Table not showing up in views list

Tags: views, 8

I am using "View Custom Table" module, and am trying to render a table from the drupal database. According to the [documentation](https://www.drupal.org/project/view_custom_table), after the Custom table is defined, it should be available as a dropdown to "Show" when creating a new View. But the Custom Table is not showing up for me in there. I have already tried clearing both Views cache, and the site cache, but none of them work.

Any ideas? or other ways of rendering a database table
[image: The custom Table is created, as the documentation suggests]

[image: But it is not showing up in the list like the documentation suggests]
[image: log message being Generated: _Notice Trying to get property of non-object in Drupal\view_custom_table\Form\AddViewsCustomTable-> buildForm()_]

Comment: Did you follow the documentation closely? You need to clear the cache before it appears in the Views list. Does your table have a primary key? Any relationships, have you added them in the settings? Any related entries in the logs? BTW your screenshots are too wide, too much unnecessary white space making the important parts harder to read.

Comment: @prkos  Yes, I have cleared both, the cache for the Views, and the cache for my website. The table does have a primary key, but no relationships to any Nodes, so I selected None for that, as the screenshots in documentation suggest.  There is a php log being generated, but I am not sure what it means.   I have added an image of the log message to the question as well, since it  is too long to copy and paste here.

Comment: You should post this to the module issues ;)